# How best to show the best model over multiple labels?

Tags: machine-learning, model-evaluations, model-selection, plotting

I have 4 models I trained and I want to display their prediction success over 45 different labels I tested them on.

I get a very messy plot when I naively try to place them one on top of the other.

Here is the bar of the 4 models over 45 labels:
[image]
And here is the line of the 4 models over 45 labels:
[image]
I thought to maybe show them in parts, meaning create like 9 graph, each graph show only 5 labels.

What I really would like to is maybe show the winner model in each label and so, the winning model's color will pop right in front of you.

How do you suggest to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are interested in the relative rank the models on each label, you may use [`ArrayPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayPlot.html) to show the rankings.

For an example series of four models' prediction success over a set of 45 labels.

```
SeedRandom[126]
modelLabels = 0.75 + RandomFunction[WienerProcess[-0.01, .08], {0, 45, 1}, 4];
modelLabels = TimeSeriesWindow[modelLabels, {1, Automatic}];

ListLinePlot[modelLabels,
 PlotStyle -> ColorData[112],
 PlotLegends -> StringTemplate["ba``"] /@ Range[2, 5]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

For the [`First`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/First.html) label

```
First@Transpose@modelLabels["ValueList"]
```

> ```
> {0.648211, 0.743796, 0.68795, 0.720637}
> ```

we can see that the [`Ordering`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ordering.html) for rank should be model 2, 4, 3, and then 1. A check of the model ordering confirms.

```
modelLableRank = Reverse@*Ordering /@ Transpose@modelLabels["ValueList"];
First@modelLableRank
```

> ```
> {2, 4, 3, 1}
> ```

These ranks can now be visualised with `ArrayPlot`.

```
ArrayPlot[Transpose@modelLableRank,
 ColorRules -> Thread[Range@4 -> ColorData[112] /@ Range@4],
 FrameTicks -> All,
 FrameLabel -> {"Rank", "Label"},
 PlotLabel -> "Model Prediction Sucess",
 PlotLegends -> Placed[StringTemplate["ba``"] /@ Range[2, 5], Below]
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

First label ranking is as expected, relative ranks and ranking patterns can be seen.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some index, such as (possibly weighted) average.

Another way would be to use 3 dimensional graph, with one of the dimensions being the task.

Comment: can you explain what you mean with the index and also about the 3 dimensional graph?

Answer (score 0):

In order to compare models, you need to define a single metric for the quality of the model.

You don't specify but I assume your model is a multiclass classifier: out of 45 labels, for each example, it needs to pick the right one.

You can calculate the F1 score of your model for each label vs the rest: how often is it able to correctly predict label 0 vs not label 0? (This is called the "one versus all" strategy.) This will give you 45 F1 scores for each model: one F1 score for each label. The plot you show suggests that all labels are more or less equally important, so you can average the F1 scores for each model and the will give you an indication of the quality of each model. If the importance of the labels varies, use a weighted average with the weight according to the importance.

Note that the plot you show just says each model predicts label 0 about 28 times, but there is no info on how often this was correct...